# Neos 1.2.9 error during loading image

Tags: neoscms

I have problem with Neos 1.2.9. It's error `"The identifier Persistence_Object_Identifier is missing for a query of TYPO3\Media\Domain\Model\Image"`. It's happened when I add image to backend. Not every time, only sometimes.  there is no principle why. One time everything is fine, next time I had this error.

I tried to do update Neos to 1.2.19 but bug still exists.

I have wasted many hours to try solution, but no result. The same image one time is loaded correctly, next time I had this error. After that I have to remove this node from database, because backend can't loading node tree.

./flow node:repair doesn't work - I have to remove manually all crashed node from database.

[image: Neos image problem]

Answer (score 1):

You are working with quite an old version. If you look at the [release roadmap](https://www.neos.io/features/release-roadmap.html) you will see that your version will run out of support.

Go to https://www.neos.io/community/social-media.html there you find the official channels (Slack or Discourse. There are much more people who can help you.